# How to import/export the intrinsic camera parameter in opencv using python?

Tags: opencv, import, export, camera-calibration

I would like to export the intrinsic parameters of my succesfully conducted camera calibration in opencv (python). I'd also like to be able to import it again. Preferable, additional information about the camera would also be exported/imported (resolution, size of pixels ...)

Do such export/import functions exist in opencv? A link would be much appreaciated.

I've read in the user-manual of the photogramemtry-software "agisoft" that it is compatible with xml-format from opencv (see quote below). I found [his thread](https://www.agisoft.com/forum/index.php?topic=2733.msg14645#msg14645), but this indicates that the export function in opencv has to be written manually(?).

Thank you very much for any useful comments on this.

> To export / import camera calibration data only select Camera Calibration... command from the Tools
> menu. Using / buttons it is possible to load / save camera calibration data in the following formats:
>
> - Agisoft Camera Calibration (*.xml)
> - Australis Camera Parameters (*.txt) \
> - Australis v7 Camera Parameters (*.txt) \
> - PhotoModeler Camera Calibration (*.ini)
> - 3DM CalibCam Camera Parameters (*.txt)
> - CalCam Camera Calibration (*.cal)
> - Inpho Camera Calibration (*.txt)
> - USGS Camera Calibration (*.txt)
> - Pix4D Camera Calibration (*.cam)
> - OpenCV Camera Calibration (*.xml)
> - Z/I Distortion Grid (*.dat)

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information, here is an example of calibration/distortion data export in OpenCV format from the mentioned software:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<calibration_Time>"Wed Nov 23 14:15:14 2022"</calibration_Time>
<image_Width>8192</image_Width>
<image_Height>5460</image_Height>
<Camera_Matrix type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>3</rows>
  <cols>3</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    8.19909097977063720e+03 0. 4.10285658215068088e+03 0.
    8.19820374050889950e+03 2.76652312492446345e+03 0. 0. 1.</data></Camera_Matrix>
<Distortion_Coefficients type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>5</rows>
  <cols>1</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    -5.05148685992756821e-02 2.30717657759454305e-02 1.39452268357952527e-03 -4.76647437649973301e-04
    -1.00095593477604744e-01</data></Distortion_Coefficients>
</opencv_storage>
```